# Spring configuration loading order

Tags: java, spring, deployment, war, ear

There is a maven-project which makes `.ear` file which contains a `.war` and `.jar`'s. All these modules use Spring configuration files which are loaded with `ContextLoaderListener`.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And actual problem is that our `.war`-module has SpringBeans which depend on some other SpringBeans which are located in `.jar`-modules. During the start of application Spring context cannot be initialized because of wrong order of finding those `context.xml`'s.

The question is, if it is possible somehow to set the correct order of loading spring contexts in web.xml?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change configuration file names for WAR and JAR - *my-war-beans.xml & my-jar-beans.xml*. Then define ContextLoaderListener so that it uses my-war-beans.xml (idea is to provide only one file as configuration entry point):

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:my-war-beans.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And then just import beans from my-jar-beans.xml in my-war-beans.xml:

```
<beans> 

    <!-- Include beans from JAR -->
    <import resource="classpath*:my-jar-beans.xml"/>

    <!-- List beans from WAR -->
    <bean id="myBean" class="myclass" />

</beans>
```

Make sure that your bean definition files have unique names. Classpath is flat so if names are same - this approach will be vulnerable to jar hell problems. Note that you may need to change URLs like "classpath*:my-jar-beans.xml" to something else, depends on where you store files inside a JAR/WAR.

Comment: yeees, it was so easy, no idea why I didn't think about it before..  thanks a lot!